# getting build commands from codelite IDE

Tags: c++, gcc, codelite

I would like to run a c++ program on my school's linux cluster, but first I need to build the executable on their machine (`scp`'ing my executable over doesn't seem to work). Usually I build everything on my machine with an IDE. So how do I get the command that the IDE put together for me?

Comment: The build command will be displayed in the IDEs build log. window. You may need to enable extra logging to see it.

Comment: ah that was easy. thanks